# Check all values of a list in if condition

Tags: python

Consider you have a *list* with you. Let's call this **test_values**.

Now consider you have an if condition, which is checking the equality of another variable against the values in **test_values**.

Snippet:

```
if(some_var != test_values[0] and
   some_var != test_values[1] and
   some_var != test_values[2] and
   some_var != test_values[3] and
   some_var != test_values[4])
```

Now for the question - what is the best way to combine the above 'and' separated statements, so I don't have to specify the list indices one-by-one?

P.S

```
if(some_var != test_values)
```

is equivalent to

```
if(some_var != test_values[0] or
   some_var != test_values[1] or
   some_var != test_values[2] or
   some_var != test_values[3] or
   some_var != test_values[4])
```

so that won't work.

Comment: You mean `if some_var not in test_values`? or to be specific `if some_var not in test_values[:5]`?

Comment: Something like `if all(some_var != i for i in test_values):`?

Comment: Thanks @KlausD.! That works perfectly. Sorry, if it seemed like a silly question, still transitioning to Python, getting used to the syntax.

Comment: Depending of what you want to compare, you might also consider using `is not` instead of `!=` because different objects can be equal, while being different. For example, `[1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]` evaluates to `True`, but `[1, 2, 3] is [1, 2, 3]` evaluates to `False` because while they have the same content and thus are equals, they are completely different objects of type `list` that happens to contain the same elements. Understanding the differences might prevent headaches in some situations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Python's `in` and a `for` loop within the condition does the trick (refer answers and comments).

Solution:

```
if(some_var != test_values[0] and
   some_var != test_values[1] and
   some_var != test_values[2] and
   some_var != test_values[3] and
   some_var != test_values[4]):
```

can be re-written as:

```
if all(some_var != i for i in test_values):
```

Comment: Which is the same, but probably slower than, `if some_var not in test_values:`.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `in` operator in python.

> x in s
>
> True if an item of s is equal to x, else False
>
> x not in s
>
> False if an item of s is equal to x, else True

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange

Your condition with `in` would become -

```
if some_var not in test_values:
    # Do something
```

If you want to test test_values within a certain range, you can use list slicing in Python.
For example, to test values till 5(but not including at index 5)

```
if some_var not in test_values[:5]:
    # Do something
```

Or from 3 to 8(not including 8)

```
if some_var not in test_values[3:8]:
    # Do something
```

More about slicing in python [here](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/)